# Construct 2, export for iOS with Ejecta and iOS8 webview result in a blank screen

Tags: ios, html, construct-2, wkwebview

I have noticed that every app created with Construct 2 and exported via Ejecta cannot play on an iOS device, that is results in a blank screen. Could this be the result of [WKWebview problem with local files](http://www.openradar.me/18039024) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so - Ejecta works well for me.

There is a tutorial on exporting with Ejecta on the C2 forums here: 
[Export to iOS with Ejecta](https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/992/how-to-export-to-ios-with-ejecta)